# CDF of minimum of random variable and constant

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables, normal-distribution

Let $X$ be a normally distributed random variable. I am trying to find the CDF of a minimum of $X$ and a constant $c$. In other words the CDF of the random variable $Y = \min (X,c)$.

With

$Y = \left\{\begin{matrix}
 X,& X < c\\ 
 c,&  X \geq c
\end{matrix}\right.$

I started with considering that $P\{\min_i X_i  > a\} = \prod_{i=1}^n P\{X_i > a\}$ for a group of random variables $X_i$ which led me to

$F_Y(x) = P(Y \leq x) = 1 - (1-F_X(x))(1-F_c(x))$

but am unsure if that is the correct approach and also how to determine $F_c(x)$.

Any further insights are much appreciated!

---

Comment: You could consider drawing the graph of $Y$ and then use it to find the CDF.

Comment: $F_c(x)=1$ if $x \geq c$ and $0$ otherwise.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, @KaviRamaMurthy. Does that mean that I can write $F_c(x) = 1*(1-F_X(c)) + 0*F_X(c) = 1-F_X(c)$?

Comment: $F_Y(x)=1$ if $x \geq c$ and $F_Y(x)=F_X(x)$ if $x<c$.

Answer (score 2):

$c$, being constant, does not have a CDF as such.   You merely need to determine if the value $x$ is less than $c$ or not.

$Y$ is distributed identically to $X$ for all values less than $c$, and the rest of the distribution lies exactly on $c$.

$$F_Y(x)= F_X(x)\mathbf 1_{x\lt c}+\mathbf 1_{x\geqslant c}$$

Comment: Thank you for the clarifying answer! What I am eventually looking for is the $n$-fold convolution of $F_Y(x)$. Is this possible to analytically obtain, given the definition in your answer?

Answer (score 2):

You know:

- for $x \lt c$: $F_Y(x)=\mathbb P(Y \le x) = \mathbb P(X \le x) =F_X(x) $
- for $x \ge c$: $F_Y(x)=\mathbb P(Y \le x) \le \mathbb P(Y \le c)= 1 $ , so $F_Y(x)=1$

The cumulative distribution functions for $X$ (red) and for $Y$ (blue) look like this:

[image]